# Missing the handle of a shower diverter

Tags: shower, diverter

We have a old shower that misses the handle of the diverter (see picture below). We asked a plumber about fixing it and were told that it's very expensive:  need to take the whole diverter out to find the handler, or to replace the whole thing.

My question is: is there a way for me to find a handle replacement and fix it? Is this a job that a regular guy can DIY?

[image]

Comment: Finding a replacement handle might be expensive to let a plumber do(60 to 100$ an hour).  Is the design important to you?  Changing parts should be DIY type if willing to buy/rent tools needed.

Comment: Any guide about how to go about changing parts?